# Show multiple text labels in a Horizontal recycler view/carousel view

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to show multiple text in a recycler view/carousel view in android/kotlin.If yes,then what would be the logic for that or what topic should I read that will help me with this.

I have attached a example diagram below.I want to create the below part,there is some other layout on top :

[image]

Really need some help over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe you're looking for a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`.

For example, when setting up your `RecyclerView`, set your `LayoutManager` to a new `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

```
// get the reference of RecyclerView
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
// set a StaggeredGridLayoutManager with 3 number of columns and vertical orientation
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
```

A more in-depth example could be found here, https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html.